# jQuery.print-preview not working in IE9

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9

I have this issue with a plug-in called [jQuery.print-preview](https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin). It works fine in FF, Safari, etc.. For some reason (I think) it conflicts with Google's custom search plug-in in IE9. If I add a meta tag to tell IE to use IE7 it works fine. But this is not really satisfying because the page renders a bit different under IE7.

I have put all the files in my test folder:
http://tinyurl.com/blnlaym

Hopefully you can help me.

Kind regards,

Jurgen

Comment: For some reason the conflict is there when I use jquery-1.9.0.min.js. If I switch to jquery 1.5.2 everything works just fine. For now I leave it like that but it would be great if somebody could tell me why 1.9 does not work in IE9.

Jurgen

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, I just discovered that the whole problem was due to the sequence of loading several scripts. It was by accident I mixed up the order. I did that before in an attempt to solve this but apparently I overlooked something.

Okay, consider this one solved.

Jurgen